# Pre-trained CNN for feature extraction

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, tensorflow, image-classification

I'm trying to classify images. I want to run each image through a pretrained CNN to apply convolution and pooling and end up with a smaller picture/matrix where the value of each pixel is a feature. Then I want to pass that to an SVM for classification.

Can someone provide code to get started with feature extraction with CNN and SVM ?

Answer (score 3):

Here's some starter code:

```
from keras.applications.vgg19 import VGG19
from keras.preprocessing import image
from keras.applications.vgg19 import preprocess_input
from keras.models import Model
import numpy as np

# define the CNN network
# Here we are using 19 layer CNN -VGG19 and initialising it
# with pretrained imagenet weights
base_model = VGG19(weights='imagenet')

# Extract features from an arbitrary intermediate layer
# like the block4 pooling layer in VGG19
model = Model(inputs=base_model.input, outputs=base_model.get_layer('block4_pool').output)

# load an image and preprocess it
img_path = 'elephant.jpg'
img = image.load_img(img_path, target_size=(224, 224))
x = image.img_to_array(img)
x = np.expand_dims(x, axis=0)
x = preprocess_input(x)

# get the features 
block4_pool_features = model.predict(x)
```

You can then use these features for passing to a SVM classfier.
Here are some additional links for reference:

[Understanding CNNS](https://adeshpande3.github.io/adeshpande3.github.io/A-Beginner%27s-Guide-To-Understanding-Convolutional-Neural-Networks/)

[Keras pretrained networks](https://keras.io/applications/)

[Coding a convolutional neural network in keras](https://elitedatascience.com/keras-tutorial-deep-learning-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

> Can anyone suggest code to use or a guide for getting started with
>   CNNs in Python?

If you are a noob to CNN, Keras is the recommended starting point. The code is self-explanatory and easy to understand. Here is a link to a [simple classification related task](http://www.codesofinterest.com/2016/11/lenet-model-for-face-recognition.html) on facial images tutorial using Keras. You can also start with [MNIST classification](https://elitedatascience.com/keras-tutorial-deep-learning-in-python) and understand the core concepts of CNN. Once you understand the fundamentals, you can try and experiment with other libraries like Tensorflow, Theano, Pytorch...etc.